# Ipad website image performance and memory

Tags: javascript, html, ipad

On iPad safari, is it better to include images as CSS background images or use the html  tag ? 
Do you have any ressources about it ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I just runned [this](http://jsperf.com/background-image-vs-img/3) test on my iPad Safari. And looks like CSS is faster.

Try it yourself on you iPad.

3 tests:
Image tag src:

```
img.onload = loadHandler;
img.src = getUrl();
```

CSS Background

```
bg.style.background = "url('" + getUrl() + "') no-repeat";
```

Image tag src without onLoad

```
img.onload = null;
img.src = getUrl();
```

Here I got the following result:

Image tag src: 5,369 Operations/Sec.

CSS background-image: 19,554 Op/S.

Image Tag Src (without OnLoad): 2,757 Op/S.

BTW, this test was not created by me.

**Edit:** As pointed to me, I did a new test to test the performance in another way.

To be more consistent, I tried to see each solution in a different way. I used the following code.

```
var count = 1;
function add(){
  var p = document.getElementById("parent");
  if (false){
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    p.appendChild(d);
    d.style.background = "url('" + getUrl() + "') no-repeat";
  } else {
    var d = document.createElement("img");
    p.appendChild(d);
    d.onload = null;
    d.src = getUrl();
  }
  d.style.position="absolute";
  d.style.top=0;
  d.style.left=0;
  d.style.zIndex=count;
  d.style.width=256;
  d.style.height=256;
}
function getUrl() {
  var base = "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/16/";
  base += count + "/" + count + ".png";
  return base;
}   
function init(){
  while(count <= 10){
    add();
    count++;
  }
}
```

*note 1:* Im using z-Index so the new add element is always on top.

*note 2:* Im loading different imgs so the browser doesnt cache.

*note 3:* I know that I tested it on a common browser. Although, we can see its behavior and discover what to expect in the iOS/Safari.

Here's what happened.

**Memory:** Both solutions kept the resource in the same way. So theres no different in memory.

**Calls:** Both solution called the same amount of paint and load. Although, the IMG always called an event. Even when I explicitly put "onload = null;".

Here's is the calls for [DIV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIrPm.png)
[image]

Here's the calls for [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk8tr.png)
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I get the same results. If I understand it is the image loading operation, but after is the image in memory takes more space with the <img> tag ? and is it removed with garbage collector ?

Comment: @dandavis you are right, the number was supposed to be 5,369. The website jsPerf keep information of all tests realized, so we can go there and check the plot of all tests.

Comment: that fiddle does not test image loading performance. it doesn't really test anything other than itself. just because the css is compared to itself before re-requesting a url doesn't mean that it's any faster than an img tag. even the img tags get cached, but the dom overhead only apparent in a warhammer-type script liked the one linked is enough to slow down the process. img tag still ping the img url, whereas unchanged css will not. if you don't load 500 of the same images, you will see no benefit...

Comment: You are right. Both solution will keep the resource (images) in the same way. So theres no solution with better "memory" management. For processing, both solution call paint the same amount of time. Although, the img always do an event call for onload. Even when you explicity put "onload = null" (I tested this on Chomium).

Answer (score 0):

Not directly an answer, but since others might end up here while searching, I figured I would share some insight:

I had a rather large css-sprite in png, that performed quite badly on ipad. Switching from png to jpg had a massive impact on the rendering performance (to the better). There seems to be some hints as to why on this page: https://gist.github.com/KrofDrakula/3639830