# Load what you see in a webpage

Tags: image, html

I have a webpage where I have to display a lot of images, so the page loads slowly. I would like to do something like google images: the images you don't see don't load.
Is there a way to do it easily?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Google: **lazy load image webpage**. However, at the same time, please spend some at reading the [FAQ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the images no src attribute, just an expando attribute, url for example.  Then you can set the src attribute when it is scrolled into view.  It may actually perform better in some environments to set the background image ([Ipad website image performance and memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000365/ipad-website-image-performance-and-memory)), so this is also worth considering. This isn't really tested code, but it should be pretty close:

```
$(function(){
  var $images = $("img");
  var iNextImageToLoad = 0;
  $(document).scroll(function(){
    for(var i = iNextImageToLoad; i < $images.length; i++){
      if( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $images.eq(i).offset().top ){
        //image is in view
        $images[i].attr(src) = $images[i].attr(url);
        iNextImageToLoad = i+1;
      }
    }

  });
});
```